# SELECT Vertex WITH multiple Edges

Tags: orientdb

This is my schema:

[image]

My objective is capture that purple Vertex with name "Paragrafo" and have connection with the Vertex "1" AND "2", in this case will be the #29:426.

I tried:

```
SELECT EXPAND( BOTH( 'Contem' ) ) FROM Topico WHERE Assunto = '1' and Assunto = '2'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Topico WHERE Assunto = '1' and Assunto = '2'
```

or

```
SELECT FROM ( SELECT EXPAND(BOTHE('Contem')) FROM Topico WHERE Assunto='2' and Assunto = '1')
```

The AND operator make the query return None.

It's possible to make a query to do that?
I'm doing my schema right?

Thanks.

Comment: You should use `WHERE Assunto IN ['1', '2']` instead of `AND`. `AND` try to apply both conditions on the same node.

Comment: That work's, thank you.

Comment: Well, that query does not work very well, it keep retriving in order.

Comment: What do you mean by "it keep retriving in order"? could you update your question with expected result and the actual result with the `IN`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select from Topico where out().<property_name> contains '1' AND out().<property_name> contains '2'
```

Hope it helps

Regards